# GCC language extension __attribute__((vector_size(16))) incompatible type error

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-errors, gcc-extensions

While using Csmith a random C program generator I tried adding a GNU C language variable extension **attribute**((vector_size(16))) for variable .

```
static uint64_t  func_1(void)
{/* block id: 0 */
    uint64_t l_6 __attribute__ ((vector_size (64)))  = 0xCD2466E9F08664A1LL;
    int32_t *l_7 /*__attribute__ ((vector_size (16)))*/ = (void*)0;
    int32_t *l_8 /*__attribute__ ((vector_size (16)))*/= &g_9;
    int32_t *l_10 = &g_5.f7;
    int32_t **l_11[10][8][3] = {{{&l_10,&l_10,&l_10},{&l_7,&l_8,&l_8},{&l_8,&l_8,(void*)0},{&l_7,&l_8,&l_10},{&l_8,&l_7,&l_10},{&l_8$
    int32_t *l_13 = &g_9;
    int i, j, k;
    (*l_8) |= (g_2[3] , (safe_rshift_func_int16_t_s_s(0L, (g_5 , (l_6 != g_5.f2)))));
    (*l_10) |= ((g_12 = l_10) != (void*)0);
    l_13 = &g_9;
    return (*l_13);

}
```

where as there are #define's provided for int8_t(like signed char),int16_t(like short) and so on.
and safe_rshift_func_int16_t_s_s is a function internally defined.

compiling the above program with gcc gives following errors:

```
sam.c: In function ‘func_1’:
sam.c:53:56: error: incompatible types when initializing type ‘__vector(8) long long unsigned int’ using type ‘long long unsigned int’
     uint64_t l_6 __attribute__ ((vector_size (64)))  = 0xCD2466E9F08664A1LL;
                                                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Is the attribute wrongly placed?
I tried referring to the documentation from the GCC portal linked [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-8.1.0/gcc/Common-Variable-Attributes.html#Common-Variable-Attributes) but unable to understand exactly the correct use of this attribute, please can anyone point them out?

Are there any restrictions so as where to use this attribute?
Thanks community. !:)

I tried searching SO and web  but most of them talk about use typedef for their solutions.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Set all elements of the vector to 0xCD2466E9F08664A1LL?

Comment: It's a random fuzzer of C language generation